# How to maintain formatting and indentation when using com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text

Tags: java, google-app-engine, formatting

So i am using `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text` to store whole Articles(String more than 500 char) in my GAE database.

Google API says that `<variableName>.getvalue()` will give the value of the Text variable!

But if i insert a String which is already indented and formatted.. i lose the formatting and the white spaces, when i use `.getValue()` function and print the Text on my webpage.

This is my code of the function the returns a HTML String to the client which then appends this HTML String to a div and displays it.

```
public void getArticle(int articleId)
{
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
Articles a  = pm.getObjectById(Articles.class,(articleId));
String html = "";
html += "<p>" + (a.getArticle()).getValue() + "</p>";
return html; 
}
```

Comment: This should not happen - `Text` saves a large stream of characters and does not format it. Try writing a test method that saves a large String as `Text`, then reads it back and compares it (using `.equals()`) with the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the HTML in `<pre>` tags to preserve the formatting.

ie

```
html += "<p><pre>" + (a.getArticle()).getValue() + "</pre></p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that browsers removes extraneous whitespace and newlines. This has nothing to do with the datastore, this would happen if you just put your content straight onto a webpage.

You either need to convert your text to html for presentation (i.e. replace newlines with 
 or wrap each actual paragraph in a

tag), or as suggested above use an html element which preserves formatting.

You can do that with a  tag, or by applying a css style rule of 'white-space: pre;' or 'white-space: pre-line;'

You can check out the white-space reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp). On this page the behaviour you're seeing is described under the value 'normal'.